# Linux directory permissions, owner can create and read but not delete

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I want to create a folder, so the owner can create and read files but not be able to delete them. I tried with ACL, but the owner can still delete the files.

```
$ setfacl --set u::rwx,g::-,o::- control
$ setfacl -d --set u::r-x,g::-,o::- control
$ touch 1.txt
$ ls -al 1.txt
-r--------. 1 user group 1.txt
$ rm 1.txt 
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `1.txt'? y
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible.  You can have read but not create or delete, but you can't have one of create or delete without the other.  Also, this is pointless, as the owner can always reset the permissions to whatever they want.

Comment: It can be done with SELinux, but that's fairly complicated. It also can be done by setting the "append only" attribute on the directory, but that comes with its own set of trickery when dealing with putting files in there.

Comment: Corey can you point me to a site has this sort of SELinux information?